# How to extract images from running .Net application?

Tags: .net, image, reverse-engineering, embedded-resource

I would ask about just ".net application" but my app is obfuscated, encrypted and compressed, and I cannot get anything from just a binary file on the disk.

This is my own app, and because of disk crash, I had to retrieve it from SVN. It appeared that I didn't include images, so I am figuring out how to get it back from installed .exe file.

So -- is there a tool to extract images from **running** .Net application? I think this is my last chance.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by compressed/encrypted - these are both reversible operations and obfuscation will not affect binaries stored in the file.

Comment: Try Just Decompile http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx and Resource Hacker http://angusj.com/resourcehacker

Comment: Guys, thanks. I use CryptoObfuscator -- it has option "encrypt" and "compress" for resources. At this point I don't know how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like [Cropper](http://cropper.codeplex.com/) to take screenshots of the images within the app?

Comment: Taking screenshots is actually just beyound last chance, because I will loose transparency information. But sure, I will use it if I have to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Assembly.Load against a .NET EXE file; I'm wondering if you can then reflect into that image and extract the resources you need ?

My thinking is, is by that time, the OS/CLR will have done whatever processing is required to unpack your image.

Comment: There are tools for that, sure, but as I wrote, the file is compressed and encrypted, so such tools do not recognize my app as .Net application.

Comment: Indeed, but I'm suggesting that you don't use tools but try to use .net itself; I'll add some more detail to the answer ...

Comment: The tool I found is with sources, so I of course took a peek why it does not work in my case. You cannot do much with exception thrown from Assembly.LoadFrom( ... )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a .Net application, you can probably use Reflector to view all the embeded resources of the various assemblies.

Comment: As I wrote -- the file is encrypted. I use CryptoObfuscator.